# Calculate previous order date and status in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, nested, vlookup

I have a simple table of orders, and I need to calculate some stats for each order. Essentially I have a Postgres db with fields:
Order_ID (unique), User_ID, Created_at (date), City, Total

I want to write a query that will generate, for each Order_ID:

1) the Created_at date of the user's most recent order prior to the current Order_ID (so if a customer placed order with Order_ID=200005b on 9/20/14, what is the date of that user's most recent previous order?)

2) another field showing a user's "Status" based on this date, given the following cases:
  -- if this is user's first order, Status="new";
  -- if most recent previous order date <= 60 days before the given/current order, Status="active";
  -- if most recent previous order date > 60 days before the given/current order, Status="reactivated"

I think there's a way to write this query using some nested SELECTS, and maybe a self-join, but I don't know PostgreSQL well enough to understand the ordering of queries. I have been able to generate an "Order_N" field using the following query that I could use to lookup (Order_N)-1 to find the date, but I get stuck once trying to use that in nesting.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  order_id,
  created_at,
  row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at ) as order_n
order by user_id, created_at;
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think you're up to [`lag()` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) here.

Comment: Thanks, I think the lag() is working! I tried the following code, which seems to work:

Comment: SELECT
  s.order_id,
  s.user_id,
  s.created_at,
  row_number() over (partition by s.user_id order by s.created_at ) as orders_sofar_placed,
  LAG(s.createdat) OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY created_at) as last_order,
  (CASE WHEN (s.created_at - LAG(s.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY created_at)) > interval '60 days' THEN 'reactivated'
       WHEN (s.created_at - LAG(s.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY created_at)) <= interval '60 days' THEN 'active'
       ELSE 'new'
  END) as cust_status
FROM
  fulfillments s;